# NPE при попытке reader.readLine;

Tags: java, файлы

Дан файл, в котором построчно хранятся данные вида:

> id name1 name2 name3.

Файл отсортирован по возрастанию по id. Мне нужен максимальный id.

Чтобы не перебирать все строки, решил схитрить и написал так (оставил только важное):

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
skipLines(fileReader);
id = Integer.parseInt(fileReader.readLine().substring(0, idMaxLength).trim());
```

...

```
public static void skipLines(BufferedReader reader) {
    int count = (int) reader.lines().count();
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
        try {
            reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

чтобы работать сразу с последней строкой. Но имею NPE на строке "id = Integer.parseInt..."

UPD: В отладке цикл нормально отрабатывает. Файл заполнен. Строка 100+ символов, idMaxLength != 0;

Comment: чтобы не вычитывать весь файл, нужно использовать [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), либо каналы из `java.nio`. При этом придется написать код, который определяет конец предпоследней строки, с учетом кодировки. В Apache commons-io есть [`ReversedLinesFileReader`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html) в котором это сделано за вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) в `BufferedReader` возвращает поток (stream) из строк файла. Чтение происходит "лениво": когда понадобится в конечной операции ("terminal stream operation"). Такой операцией является метод `count`, и в результате его применения из reader-а считываются все строки.

В итоге что в `skipLines` метод [readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) возвращает `count - 1` раз null (так как все строки уже считаны), что в основном коде (по той же самой причине).

Достаточно просто считывать строки до тех пор, пока не дойдёте до null, и возвращать последнюю не null-овую строку:

```
String lastLine = "";
String line;
while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    lastLine = line;
}
id = Integer.parseInt(lastLine.substring(0, idMaxLength).trim());
```